# Matplotlib from json attributes in python

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, attributes

I'm trying to turn this json file attributes into matplotlib where x in plot "shows number of follower" and y "frequency of users who have that specific amount of follower".

this is how my json file looks like

```
[{"user": "person1", "follower": 1008, "following": 2520},
 {"user": "person2", "follower": 144, "person3": 394},
 {"user": "person4", "follower": 483, "following": 1582},...]
```

I have already imported json file into python but I can't figure it out how to use specific attribute for drawing plot in matplotlib(not pandas plot)

```
import pandas as pd
import json
instagram = json.loads(open('J:\\data.json').read())
df = pd.DataFrame(instagram)
print (df)
df.plot(x='user', y='follower')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can show followers on x axis and frequency of users with that number of followers on y axis

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# if you are running in jupyter notebook - uncomment the below line
# %matplotlib inline

d = [{"user": "person1", "follower": 1008, "following": 2520},\
     {"user": "person6", "follower": 1008, "following": 2520},\
     {"user": "person7", "follower": 1008, "following": 2520},\
     {"user": "person3", "follower": 1008, "following": 123},\
     {"user": "person2", "follower": 144, "following": 394},\
     {"user": "person5", "follower": 144, "following": 987},\
     {"user": "person4", "follower": 483, "following": 1582}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
dfg = df.groupby('follower').count()

# using matplotlib scatter chart
plt.scatter(x=dfg.index, y=dfg['user'])
plt.show()

# using pandas plot
dfg.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
plt.show()
```